# How to install Sun Path addon (Blender 2.8x)?

Tags: add-on, installation

- Tutorial for version 2.63 that works with a sunpath package:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsovmL9hv80
- Sunpath version that works with 2.71 here: https://www.ods-engineering.com/tools/ods-studio/download/#4
- Python package for performing high-precision astronomy computations here:
  https://pypi.org/project/pyephem/

**Q:** How to install the *Sun Path* addon in newer versions of Blender?

Comment: [Sun Position Addon](https://en.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Sun_Position)  and this [from old BA thread](https://blenderartists.org/t/geographic-sun-addon/500251/17?u=batfinger)  wouldn't be too hard to update to 2.8

Comment: I am not sure if anyone is updating it. Or is there an existing way to import the python package for it?

Comment: sun path (sun pos) 2.8 Version [Very realistic sun studies for architects: github kevancress/sun_position_b28_test ](https://blenderartists.org/t/very-realistic-sun-studies-for-architects/532395/143)

Comment: 2.80 compatible almost full functional but named as "test"
https://github.com/kevancress/sun_position_b28_test

Answer (score 1):

Manage to find the python scripts here:
https://github.com/ccamara/blender-architecture-scripts/tree/master/addons/sun_position